# Static or Dynamic linking in R?

Tags: r

If we import a module in an R script and use its functions, does it count as static linking or does it count as dynamic linking? Asking this as our legal department wants to understand the type of linking used when we use open source libraries. The type of linking is apparently important for complying with certain open source usage guidelines.

Comment: Static and dynamic linking are terms normally used in compiled languages like C, C++, and Java, where the compilation units need to be linked by a dedicated linker program to generate an executable file. In contrast, R is an interpreted language. If all you are doing is writing R scripts that use some freely available packages, then you are not really _linking_ anything. External packages are only loaded and used at run-time, and are therefore being used dynamically. You can reassure your legal department that you are not statically linking any existing software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static and dynamic linking are terms normally used in *compiled* languages like C, C++, and Java, where each implementation file is first built into an object file by the *compiler*. These individual compilation units then need to be *linked* by a dedicated *linker* to generate a complete program. If some of the code you use to generate the object files are from an external library, then you have *statically linked* that library. In other words, the external software is 'baked in' to your own software.

In contrast, R is an interpreted language. When you use an external package, it is loaded at run time and only when needed. It therefore always works *dynamically*. If all you are doing is writing R scripts that use some freely available packages (e.g. from CRAN using `install.packages`), then you are not really linking *anything*, and you can reassure your legal department that you are not statically linking any existing software.

Even in the case where your R script will only run on other machines if the other machines have certain packages installed, your software does not *contain* those packages.

The only time static linking might occur when writing R software is if you are writing a package and specifically writing compiled code for it, but if you were at the stage of doing that, then you would already know whether you were writing statically linked code.

Comment: I agree that it is not a case of static linking. However since the package is loaded dynamically, when the calls are made to the functions in the package, does it count as dynamic linking?